# How to run openERP as a user but using a different database username?

Tags: bash, postgresql, python-2.7, odoo

I run my OpenERP through this command:

```
ghelo@pc$ /usr/bin/python2 openerp-server -c my_config.conf
```

I have these as database credentials:

```
username:  odoo
password:  some_password
```

My `my_config.conf` file has these relative lines:

```
db_host = False
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = some_password
db_port = False
db_template = template1
db_user = odoo
dbfilter = .*
```

My `pg_hba.conf` file has these append, restarting the sevice `postgresql` at every edit:

```
host  all ghelo all md5
local all odoo      trust
```

However running the server raises this exemption:

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "odoo"
```

My question is, **how can i run the OpenERP server?**

Other Facts:

1. `odoo` has a bash account via: `$ sudo useradd odoo`
2. `psql`: `# CREATE USER odoo WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN CREATEDB INHERIT PASSWORD 'some_password';`
3. `psql`: `# CREATE DATABASE odoo OWNER odoo;`

Unfortunately I have these limitations:

1. I cannot run `sudo -u odoo COMMAND` or any bash command to use a different bash user.
2. I can only run using `/usr/bin/python2`.
3. Bash username and database username cannot be the same.

Answer (score 5):

I feel silly, I have been `rule of precedence`-ed.  The ordering of lines in `pg_hba.conf` matter.  I solved the issue by:

Placing this line:

```
local   all             odoo                                    trust
```

Just before:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

and then restart your postgresql service from root user using this command:
`systemctl restart postgresql.service`